# Transfer multiple arguments to a shell script from Jenkinsfile

Tags: unix, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkinsfile which takes multiple parameters that user enters. I need to transfer these arguments to a shell script.

```
pipeline {
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout()
        timestamps()
    }
    parameters {
        string(name: 'FILENAME', defaultValue: 'tmp', description: 'Enter the file name that needs to be copied')
        string(name: 'DB_NAME', defaultValue: 'xyz', description: 'Enter the database that needs to be created')
        string(name: 'VERSION', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter the DB name version')
        choice(name: 'RUN', choices: 'Migrate Data', description: 'Data migration')
    }
    agent {
        node { label 'ci-build-node-01' }
    }
    triggers {
        pollSCM('H/5 * * * *')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Clean & Clone') {
            steps {
                cleanWs()
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        stage('Run the shell script On-prem'){
            steps {
                configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'env-on-prem', targetLocation: '.env')]) {
                    sh  '''
                            export \$(egrep -v '^#' .env)
                            /deploy/deploy.sh

                        '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

May I please know how do I tranfer multiple parameters such as `${FILENAME}`, `${DB_NAME}` and `${VERSION}` to the shell script deploy.sh?

Answer (score 1):

To access parameters you would use : `${params.<parametername>}`.
So in your case it would be `${params.FILENAME}`
Example to pass in shell script :

```
sh "deploy.sh ${params.FILENAME} ${params.DB_NAME}"
```

Comment: yes inside ``steps{ sh "deploy.sh ${params.FILENAME} ${params.DB_NAME}" }``

Comment: I am not using this format, please check the question/ answer above.

Comment: @merilstack : yes that was an example of how to pass multiple parameters as arguments to shell script and also to access parameter using ``${params.<parameter>}``The way of access would remain same in any format.

Comment: @merilstack what is the error that you get

Comment: I am not able to access these parameters @altaf, once I use $${params.<parameter>} to transfer these parameters from Jenkinsfile, should I access them using ${params.<parameter>} or ${<parameter>} in the shell script?

Comment: @merilstack : can you just print and check ``println ${params.FILENAME}``. Does it give you the desired output. And then in your sh command ``sh "deploy.sh ${params.FILENAME} "``.

Answer (score 0):

As per your answer @altaf, the entire script will be:

```
pipeline {
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout()
        timestamps()
    }
    parameters {
        string(name: 'FILENAME', defaultValue: 'tmp', description: 'Enter the file name that needs to be copied')
        string(name: 'DB_NAME', defaultValue: 'xyz', description: 'Enter the database that needs to be created')
        string(name: 'VERSION', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter the DB name version')
        choice(name: 'RUN', choices: 'Migrate Data', description: 'Data migration')
    }
    agent {
        node { label 'ci-build-node-01' }
    }
    triggers {
        pollSCM('H/5 * * * *')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Clean & Clone') {
            steps {
                cleanWs()
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        stage('Run the shell script On-prem'){
            steps {
                configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'env-on-prem', targetLocation: '.env')]) {
                    sh  '''
                            export \$(egrep -v '^#' .env)
                            /deploy/deploy.sh ${params.FILENAME} ${params.DB_NAME} ${params.VERSION}

                        '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Like this?